# Typescript: use private object in static function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

How can i use `Angular Material` with Typescript in a pretty-code way?

For example, i do not want to write in every place where i use SnackBar this:

```
constructor(public snackBar: MdSnackBar) {}


***
this.snackBar.open('text', {
  duration: 500
}); // and i need to add this yet 10 times: no to good
***
```

i want to create a separate class, and call only it (static function), like:

```
constructor(private snackBar: MdSnackBar) {
}

public static showSnackBar(text: string, config: string): void {
  this.snackBar.open(text, config);
}
```

but so i got error:

`Property 'snackBar' does not exist on type 'typeof SnackBar'.`

when i transform my code:

```
  static snackBar: MdSnackBar;

  constructor() {
  }

  public static showSnackBar(text: string, config: string): void {
    SnackBar.snackBar.open(text);
  }
```

and call it from another classed, i got:

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
error_handler.js:52 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:52
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
error_handler.js:53 TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
    at Function.SnackBar.showSnackBar (snack-bar.ts:13)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (edit.component.ts:78)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:223)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:172)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:83)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:53
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
Subscriber.js:227 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
    at Function.SnackBar.showSnackBar (snack-bar.ts:13)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (edit.component.ts:78)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:223)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:172)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:83)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
SnackBar.showSnackBar @ snack-bar.ts:13
(anonymous) @ edit.component.ts:78
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
onLoad @ xhr_backend.js:72
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265
onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:227
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:264
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
```

what i do wrong, what i misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

If its a static function you can only use **static** members of 'this'

Answer (score 0):

You can create static methods in a class and then import them by the class name.

Example:

```
export class AStaticServiceClass {

  static doStuff(){
    return "I'm Static";
  }
}
```

and use it wherever you want as:

```
this.name = AStaticServiceClass.doStuff();
```

by importing the class.

Full plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/NWRSuaUpzkPEP3gL1DKK?p=preview

Comment: @k1882617 can you add your static method class to the question? In fact can you write the class names on top of the functions you provided? It's really confusing to recognize which class is which

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I used with same situation like in the question content.

Step 1: Crate a class with static function for show the message using snackbar

```
export class AlertMessageUtils {

  private static snackBar: MatSnackBar;         

  public static setSnackBar(snackBar: MatSnackBar){

    this.snackBar = snackBar;
  }

  public static showAlert(message: string, duration: number, positionV: any, positionH: any){
 
    this.snackBar.open(message, 'Close', {
      duration: duration * 1000,
      verticalPosition: positionV,
      horizontalPosition: positionH
    });
  }

}
```

Step 2: update the app component - set the MatSnackBar into the AlertMessageUtils class.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar ){ }  

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   
    AlertMessageUtils.setSnackBar(this.snackBar);
  }

}
```

Step 3: Now we can use the AlertmessageUtils all over the application by Just calling its static function like follows

```
AlertMessageUtils.showAlert('This is a test message...', 5, 'top', 'center');
```